# How could the Gate-Source potential difference be neglected?

Tags: power-electronics, semiconductors, electrical

I’ve been reading the book

> Electronic Principles by Malvino

In the Voltage-Divider bias section of JFET, if gate current is negligible then how did Gate Voltage attain a negative value, given Vdd is a positive value.

And also, to calculate drain current Gate-Source potential difference was neglected compared to Gate voltage.

[image: This a diagram for JFET VDB]

How were the above conclusions drawn?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Please provide a schematic.

Comment: The author assumed that the Vg voltage is a much larger than |Vgs| voltage. And this is why he writes Id = (Vg - |Vgs|)/Rs ≈ Vg/Rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you have this circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpQxZK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And the JFET parameter are:

\$I_{DSS} = 2\textrm{mA}\$ , \$V_P = -1V\$

And we want the drain current to be equal to \$1\textrm{mA}\$

The drain current describe this equation:

$$I_D = I_{DSS} \left(1 -\frac{V_{GS}}{V_P}\right)^2 $$

And we need to know \$V_{GS}\$ for \$I_D = 1\textrm{mA}\$

$$V_{GS} = V_P \left(1 -\sqrt{\frac{I_D}{I_{DSS}}}\right) = -1V \left(1 -\sqrt{\frac{1\textrm{mA}}{2\textrm{mA}}}\right) = -0.292V$$

This result tells us that we need to set the Gate voltage lower than the Source voltage by \$0.292V\$

So if I choose \$V_S\$  we can solve for source resistor

\$R_S = \frac{1V}{1\textrm{mA}} = 1\textrm{k}\Omega\$

And the voltage divider output voltage needs to be equal to:

\$V_G = V_S + Vgs = 1V + (-0.292V) = 0.708V\$

And now you can choose the voltage divider resistors values. 
For example

\$R_1 = 510\textrm{k}\Omega\$ and \$R_2 = 39\textrm{k}\Omega\$

Will met our requirements.

As you can see by choosing the proper \$V_G\$ voltage and \$R_S\$ we can set the drain current.

And If you would like to check it.

We need to solve this quadratic equation

$$I_D = I_{DSS}\left(1 - \frac{V_G - I_D\cdot R_S}{V_P}\right)^2 = 2\left(1 - \frac{10*\frac{39}{39+510} - I_D\cdot 1}{-1}\right)^2$$

And the solution is

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+%3D+2+(1+-+(10*39%2F(39%2B510)-x*1)%2F-1.0)%5E2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%20%3D%202%20(1%20-%20(10*39%2F(39%2B510)-x*1)%2F-1.0)%5E2)

\$I_D = 1.00242 \textrm{mA}\$

Comment: Pardon for asking such questions. How did you decide source voltage would be 1V?

Comment: I just pick this value randomly as a designer. I could pick Vs =2V but then Vg must be equal to  2V - 0.292V = 1.7V